# Write an O(n) algorithm that uses the above expansion to compute sin(x) for arbitrary values of n ≥ 1, with x of type float

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

> Write an O(n) algorithm that uses the above expansion to compute sin(x) for arbitrary values of n ≥ 1, with x of type float
>
> The sine of an angle x (in radians) can be computed using the n-term expansion:
>
> sin (x) = x – (x3 / 3!) + (x5 / 5!) - (x7 / 7!) + ….. ( n terms)
>    = Σ1 ≤ i ≤ n (-1)i+1 x
>   2i-1 / (2i-1)!

so i tried to do it like

```
float sin ( float x,int n){
    float y = -x;
    float s = 1.0;
    float sum = s;
    for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++) {
        int m = (2*i-1) s = y/((m-1)*m)*s;
        sum += s;
        return sum;
```

is it correct? the complexity is O(n) but i feel like there is something wrong in the algorithm

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++) {` should be `for(int i = 1; i<=n;i++) {` so that i starts at 1

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Then, extract and provide a [mcve]. Also consider codereview.stackexchange.com. Your code isn't even complete, so any comment is partial guessing.

Answer (score 0):

in code you provided

```
float sin ( float x,int n){
    float y = -x;
    float s = 1.0;
    float sum = s;
    for(int i = 0; i<=n;i++) {
        int m = (2*i-1)
        s = y/((m-1)*m)*s;
        sum += s;
        return sum;
```

- at each `i`, you multiply by `(-x)` but it should be `x^2(-1)`
- if `s` denotes your previous term in the sequence
  the `ith` deminominator `d_i` is `(2i+1)!`
  the previous denominator was `(2(i-1)+1)! = (2i-1)!`
  thus `d_i = d_{i-1} * 2i * (2i+1)`
- you initialize `s` to be `1`, but first term is `x`

correction be like

```
float my_sin(float x, int n){
    float s = x;
    float sum = s;
    for(int i = 1; i<=n;i++) {
        int m = 2*i;
        s *= ((-1))*x*x/m/(m+1);
        sum += s;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

```js
function sin(x, n){
    let s = x;
    let sum = s;
    for(let i = 1; i<=n;i++) {
        let m = 2*i;
        s *= ((-1))*x*x/m/(m+1);
        sum += s;
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(sin(Math.PI/2, 10), sin(Math.PI/3, 10), sin(0, 10))
```